# Data from My Server to Salesforce Leads

Tags: apex, leads, apex-email-service

I am new to Salesforce, I have created a web application to collect pdf documents and other details like name, contact, email etc from the user. I want to push all the data including pdf files to salesforce leads or accounts object.

After research, I found that we can do it using Email Service, where the user will send an email with all the data and attachments, and it will save it in accounts object.

Which is working but it is not showing images in FILES and `system.debug` is showing that image is uploaded.

below is the code

```
global class LeadEmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
       System.debug('Email  '+email);
      Account l;
      Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

      try {
        l = new Account();

        String emailBody = email.plainTextbody;
        String plainbodySanitised = emailbody.stripHtmlTags();

        //Map < String, Object > bodyDataKeyValuePair = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(plainbodySanitised);
        //Populate the lead fields using this way
         // if(bodyDataKeyValuePair.get('Name') != null){   
                 l.Name = 'ABC456';
                 insert l;
         // }else{
             // System.debug('VALUE NULL');
         // }
        //to save attachment to the newly inserted lead. Attachment size currently via inbound mail is restricted to 5MB
          if(email.textAttachments != null){
               for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment: email.textAttachments) {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                    attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
                    attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
                    attachment.ParentId = l.Id;
                    insert attachment;
                }
          }else if(email.binaryAttachments != null){
               for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                  Attachment attachmentb = new Attachment();
                  attachmentb.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
                  attachmentb.Body = bAttachment.body;
                  attachmentb.ParentId = l.Id;
                  insert attachmentb;
                }

              System.debug('Binary Image uploaded');
          }else{
              System.debug('No file');
          }

        result.success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.success = false;
        result.message = 'Failed to insert Lead.' + e.getMessage();
        System.debug('Failed to insert Lead.' + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

I want pdf files and all details to be saved in leads or attachment objects from my db.

Please let me know what should I do to achieve,

Answer (score -2):

Did you make "Email Service" for Inbound Email Service , You have do one thing if you didn't done that .[image]

Just check this checkbox in you email service i hope , it'll work. Your code is fine. just go on search box type Email Service and Edit you email service and checked the checkbox, as mentioned in above picture.
If your problem'll be solved then please checked this question as answered.

Comment: And also set "Accept Attachments" as "All" in Email service as mentioned above picture but i didn't highlighted this. So You have to change two field- (1.) Accept Attachments ----> "All"     (2.) Convert Text Attachments to Binary Attachments ----> "checked"

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have already done it. But still no luck.

Comment: I wan to see binary attachments to the files related to the object like accounts, contact, leads etc. Suppose I am creating a record of lead and attaching a pdf file through email service. I want to see the file attached in FIles section of the lead but I am unable to see it.

Comment: Yes , i understood , just follow that as I mentioned above . Did you follow above instructions ?

Comment: Yes. But still no luck

Comment: http://prnt.sc/mtwo4q I want to see the attached files here

Comment: OK , Let me check

Comment: http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/salesforce-email-service/            you can check this link .

Comment: I am getting the name and everything in the sfdc but I want to get files which are attached to the email. Which is the main problem.